How to structure sub sub commands with golang cobra?
I'm new to go and cobra, and I've been following tutorials/reading on how to structure the files/folders for commands, but I've come unstuck when I've added a subcommand to my commands, and hoping for a few pointers
I have this layout
--cmd
  |-cli
      |--foo
      |--foo.go
         |--bar
            |--bar.go

This works perfectly fine (also works with go build)
go run .\main.go foo bar
For reference foo.go imports bar.go and I added it as a command to foo but bar doesn't show in help: i.e: go run .\main.go foo --help
or: go run .\main.go --help
I've looked at other posts on this on stack overflow, but not seen any clarity for structure or help not showing for sub subcommands

Did you add the subcommand to the parent? Did you defined a run function for your command?

I had run defined within the command definition itself, ie.
return &cobra.Command {
Use: "foo"
short: "fooo"
Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command. args []string) { cmd.Help()} but obviously this is not adding the subcommand to the parent

Adding the subcommand as you have suggested fixed the problem!

I noticed that if you don't define a run function to your subcommand, it wont show in help.

I'm new to cobra aswell, maybesomeone will have a better answer to that, or a better example

Here is a sample code to make everything works.
If you prefer, take a look at this repo
<root_folder>/main.go
package main

import "github.com/dev-vinicius-andrade/go-cobra-example/cmd/foo"

func main() {
    foo.CreateCommand().Execute()

}

<root_folder>/cmd/foo/foo.go
package foo

import (
    "github.com/dev-vinicius-andrade/go-cobra-example/cmd/foo/bar"
    "github.com/dev-vinicius-andrade/go-cobra-example/types"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

type commandDefinition struct {
    Context       *types.CliContext
    ParentCommand *cobra.Command
}

var context = types.CliContext{}

func CreateCommand() *cobra.Command {
    c := commandDefinition{}
    return c.CreateCommandDefinition()
}
func (c *commandDefinition) CreateCommandDefinition() *cobra.Command {
    command := cobra.Command{
        Use:              "foo",
        Short:            "Foo is the main command of this tool",
        Long:             `This is a long description of Foo is the main command of this tool`,
        Aliases:          []string{},
        TraverseChildren: true, // This is important to always run the Run function of the parent command, good for global flags, context, etc
    }
    defineFlags(&command)
    defineSubCommands(&command)
    setRunCommand(&command)

    return &command
}

func defineSubCommands(cmd *cobra.Command) {
    bar.CreateCommand(&context, cmd)
}

func runCommand(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {

    if len(args) == 0 {
        cmd.Help()
        return
    }
}

func setRunCommand(command *cobra.Command) {
    command.Run = runCommand
}
func defineFlags(command *cobra.Command) {
    command.PersistentFlags().StringVarP(&context.GlobalMessage, "message", "m", "Default Global Message", "Global message to be used in all commands")
}

<root_folder>/cmd/foo/bar/bar.go
package bar

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/dev-vinicius-andrade/go-cobra-example/helpers"
    "github.com/dev-vinicius-andrade/go-cobra-example/types"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

type commandDefinition struct {
    Context       *types.CliContext
    ParentCommand *cobra.Command
}

func CreateCommand(context *types.CliContext, parentCommand *cobra.Command) (*cobra.Command, error) {
    command := commandDefinition{
        Context:       context,
        ParentCommand: parentCommand,
    }
    return command.createCommandDefinition(context, parentCommand), nil
}
func (c *commandDefinition) createCommandDefinition(context *types.CliContext, parentCommand *cobra.Command) *cobra.Command {
    command := cobra.Command{
        Use:              "bar",
        Short:            "Bar is subcommand of foo",
        Long:             `This is a long description of Bar is a subcommand of foo`,
        Aliases:          []string{},
        TraverseChildren: true,
    }
    defineFlags(&command)
    defineSubCommands(&command)
    setRunCommand(context, &command)
    helpers.CobraHelper.AddCommandToParent(&command, parentCommand)
    return &command
}

func defineSubCommands(cmd *cobra.Command) {
    //define your subcommands here
}

func runCommand(context *types.CliContext, cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", context.GlobalMessage)
}

func setRunCommand(context *types.CliContext, command *cobra.Command) {
    command.Run = func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        runCommand(context, cmd, args)
    }
}
func defineFlags(command *cobra.Command) {
    //define your flags of your subcommand here
}



<root_folder>/types/types.go
package types

type CliContext struct {
    // ...
    GlobalMessage string
    // ...
}

<root_folder>/helpers/cobra.go
package helpers

import "github.com/spf13/cobra"

type cobraHelper struct{}

func (c *cobraHelper) AddCommandToParent(command *cobra.Command, parentCommand *cobra.Command) {
    if parentCommand == nil {
        return
    } else {
        parentCommand.AddCommand(command)
    }
}

var CobraHelper = cobraHelper{}



Thank you for this, I wish I could upvote but I don't have enough karma yet

No problems, glad I helped.
